# How to specify regex for route on content processor in NiFi?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

In nifi, I am routing based on content. I am using nifi's RouteOnContent So, how can I route by specifying the regex

My input content is:

```
{
"testreg":{
"test1":"test2",
"test3":"test4"
}
}
```

I wanted to test whether `testreg` whole content(word) present in the flowfile content.
So, I checked with

1. `testreg`
2. `(testreg)`
3. `.*testreg.*`
4. `(.*testreg.*)`

But it is not matching with content, So, what is the correct regex to be used in Nifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** It'ld make very much sense to check if the pattern we are looking for is surrounded by quotes and followed by a colon, since the patern `testreg` can simply occur somewhere else too. In this case we get the last match, which is not [OK](https://regex101.com/r/HYmikZ/5). So, eventually, this:

```
[\s\S]*?(?<=")(testreg)(?=":)[\s\S]*?
```

would be the ideal answer that we are looking for.

---

Maybe, here we want to have an expression that would pass the new lines. I'm not so sure what our desired output would be, however we can start testing against a few options, such as these expressions:

```
[\s\S]*(testreg)[\s\S]*
```

---

```
[\w\W]*(testreg)[\w\W]*
```

---

```
[\d\D]*(testreg)[\d\D]*
```

---

```
([\s\S].*?)(testreg)?
```

---

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HYmikZ/1)

This demo shows that we can capture and return our desired `testreg`:

```js
const regex = /[\s\S]*(testreg)[\s\S]*/gm;
const str = `{
"testreg":{
"test1":"test2",
"test3":"test4"
}
}`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```